# my application deploys on netlify when i build it locally but it doesnt work when i deploy it from github

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, npm, netlify

Okay so i recently finished my portfolio and i wanted to host it on **netlify** through **github** but it failed.
Their docs and build log are so confusing that i do not know how to trouble shoot the problem. However, when i ran
`npm run build`
**locally on my system and then i dragged it onto netlify, it worked**.
I'm not saying i cant just keep doing this for all my websites but i would like to know any potential reason as to why it didn't work when i tried it from github.

For context, the current `node` version is `16` and the one i am using on my system is version `14`. I'm not sure whether that is enough to affect the build from github but i just thought i would mention it. if However, that is a reason as to why it isn't deploying from github then how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it throwing errors when you are deploying your site from GitHub or what? I am sure you have created a GitHub repository and logged/signed into netlify with GitHub (and authorize it). And from there(netlify's dashboard) to Team overview > Add new site > Import an existing > GitHub (it will again ask for authorization) > Pick a repository > and > Deploy site (with default settings).

This should pretty much deploy your website without any troubles. Now you can also try commit to your GitHub repository and it would automatically trigger deploy of your website on netilfy (what you call a continuous deployment).